# Support cyrillic domains

Tags: jelastic

Is there cyrillic domain names supported in jelastic?
If so, how can I bind it?

I tried to bind it in cyrillic symbols and in xn-- standart. But there are error (forbidden signs in domain name) and I can't bind domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Cyrillic domain names will be supported in jelastic 2.5 release.
Release time is end of summer.